# Как установить GMP (math functions) for PHP on CentOS

Tags: php, centos6

Вот такая ошибка

> Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'GMP extension seems not
>   to be installed' in /home..../ Stack trace: #0 /home/...(6):
>   require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /home... on line 10

В общеп понятно что нет `GMP` библиотеки.

В `php.ini ;extension=php_gmp.dll` если раскомментирую проблема не решается. В консоле пишет что не находит эту библиотеку. И насколько я понимаю эта настройка как только для виндовса.

Для `Centos` вроде есть команда для установки `GMP`
`yum -y install php-gmp` эта команда вроде скачивает и устанавливает 
`php-gmp-5.6.33-1.el6.remi.x86_64` такой файл.
Но это не решает проблему. Что дальше делать не пойму. Что угодно пробовал ничего не могу с этим поделать.

Comment: Решил эту проблему. В php.ini вместо
extension=php_gmp.dll
extension=здесь путь к файлу другой был и расширение у него линуксовское
Нашел файл поиском через консоль find / -name "*gmp*" -print

Answer (score 0):

Решил эту проблему. В php.ini вместо

> extension=php_gmp.dll

extension=здесь путь к файлу другой был и расширение у него линуксовское.
Нашел файл поиском через консоль `find / -name "*gmp*" -print` 
Из всех каталогов там только один был со словами php /modules его скопировал добавил в php.ini. 
В консоле проверил командой php -v ошибку не выдало.
После в `phpinfo()` уже отображалась инфа о GMP.